# Vue.js - how to properly conditionally set click handler code

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Currently, I have a modal that pops up with a button on it.  Depending on some data coming down, I am changing the text and functionality of the button on the modal.  I am using a computed to change the button text and another computed to change the button `@click` code.  If the condition is true, it sets the button's `@click` code to another javascript method.

I'm finding that as soon the modal gets opened, that function that is supposed to be getting attached to the `@click` of the button is actually getting called and run.  Obviously, this is not what I want.

Vue component HTML code:

```
<button
  variant="primary"
  outline
  type="button"
  @click="continueButtonClick"
>
  {{ continueButtonText }}
</button>
```

Vue component JS code:

```
computed: {
  continueButtonClick() {
    let vm = this;
    let click = vm.close;
    console.log("itemMapText: ", vm.item.itemMapText);
    if(vm.item.itemMapText === "map_displayText_viewPriceInCart") {
      click = vm.updateCartVue(vm.item.itemId);
    }
    return click;
  },
  continueButtonText() {
    let vm = this;
    let buttonText = "Continue Shopping";
    if(vm.item.itemMapText === "map_displayText_viewPriceInCart") {
      buttonText = "Remove From Cart";
    }
    return buttonText;
  },
```

Also, the `vm.close` does seem to be getting properly attached as that only runs when the button is clicked.

Comment: Vue does a pretty good job with this bindinds so please forget about angular trick `vm = this`. You do not need that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please don't do that !** Vue wants you to separate state from code from markup. If you change the event listener conditionally, you've got a little bit of state living in the markup. @click should just point to a method, and all the conditional logic should be in the method. Just use `if()` inside your handler in the methods block to differentiate the two cases. It will be much easier to follow.

The thing about computed is that you don't know/shouldn't care when it runs. I suppose you could get into returning a function from a computed, using bind() to link the arguments, but I recoil in horror. I can't see why it has to be so complex.

Comment: Hah, thanks for the correction!  Helps to have someone else that knows this stuff a little better look at it!